# Formula for this diminishing function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, closed-form, geometric-series

I'm trying to write a function for a game where points accumulated becomes less effective as they get more.

> **Input Value: 2000**
>
> **Interval: 500**

For every interval reached, decrease the effectivity of remaining input value by half. For example.

> 0 ~ 500 = 500 (1:1 conversion)
>
> 501 ~ 1000 = 250 (2:1 conversion)
>
> 1001 ~ 1500 = 125 (4:1 conversion)
>
> 1501 ~ 2000 = 62.5 (8:1 conversion)

Then get the total of the above to come up with the final value

> Final = 500 + 250 + 125 + 62.5
>
> **Final = 937.5**

How would I write this in a formula without recursions?

Comment: Hint: geometric series and its sum. Look it up on Wikipedia. The value of $r$ seems to be $r=\frac{1}{2}$ in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sum is a [geometric sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), and a standard way to find the closed form for the sum is
\begin{eqnarray*}
500+250+125+62.5&=&500\times1+500\times\frac{1}{2}+500\times\frac{1}{4}+500\times\frac{1}{8}\\
&=&500\times\left(\frac1{2^0}+\frac1{2^1}+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3}\right),
\end{eqnarray*}
where the sum has the following nice property;
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac1{2^0}+\frac1{2^1}+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3}\right)=1-\frac{1}{2^4},$$
which shows that
$$\frac1{2^0}+\frac1{2^1}+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^4}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^4}\right).$$
So your original sum can be compactly written as
$$500+250+125+62.5=500\times2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^4}\right).$$
For different interval sizes or input values, you can change the values $500$ and $4=\frac{2000}{500}$ accordingly.

Comment: Oh! Why didn't I think of that lol. I was using geometric series for exponentially increasing values before lol. Thanks! I guess the next problem is including "2000" formula and handle values that are not divisible by the interval value.

Comment: Glad I could help. For your next problem; if the interval value is $d$ and the input value is $x$, then dividing $x$ by $d$ with remainder yields integers $q$ and $r$ with $r<d$ such that $x=qd+r$. Then plug in $d$ and $q$ into the formula above, and then add $r$ times final value to get the sum
$$d\times2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^q}\right)+r\times\frac{d}{2^q}.$$

Comment: Got it! I just need to deduct number of intervals by 1 and use your formula. Then, get the excess value using modulo. excessResult = excessValue / 2^(numInterval-1). Finally, add this to your formula.

Thanks!